# FusionCharts not woking after upgrade

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

after upgrading fusion chart 3.15 to chart is not working. please help me to solve this issue.

here is the my code

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="minifier/jvs/fusioncharts.js"></script>
```

FusionCharts.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

       var chart = new FusionCharts("minifier/jvs/chart.swf?ChartNoDataText=Please select a record above", "ChartId", "370", "197", "0", "0");
```

chart.setDataXML("{$users}");

```
       chart.render("chartdiv");

    </script>
```

Comment: 3.15 is a javascript version, however, based on your code you are using SWF files which is deprecated please upgrade to the latest code you can check this link - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/upgrading/from-flash-to-javascript

Comment: Thanks. i did it.